Why does object behavior differ when assigned to local vs global/class scope?
In the code below, the WiFiClient object changes behavior depending on whether it is assigned to a locally scoped or non-locally scoped variable.
Locally scoped:
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "[redacted]";    // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "[redacted]";        // your network password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
        status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
        delay(5000);
    }
   
    server.begin();
}


void loop()
{
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
        Serial.println("new client connected");
        String currentLine = "";
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {
                char c = client.read();
                Serial.write(c);
                if (c == '\n') {
                    if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
                        //do something
                    } else {
                        currentLine = "";
                    }
                } else if (c != '\r') {
                    currentLine += c;
                }
            }
        }
        client.stop();
        Serial.println("client disconnected");
    }
}

Output (when client connects):
// execution resumes here from blocking server.available() after a client connects ...

[INFO] A client connected to this server :
[PORT]: 58620
[IP]:192.168.2.36

new client connected
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.172
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fil;q=0.8
Cookie: __guid=259319114.1308697201864418800.1719734660203.9114

Non-locally scoped:
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "[redacted]";    // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "[redacted]";        // your network password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer server(80);
WiFiClient client;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
        status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
        delay(5000);
    }
   
    server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    client = server.available();
    if (client) {
        Serial.println("new client connected");
        String currentLine = "";
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {
                char c = client.read();
                Serial.write(c);
                if (c == '\n') {
                    if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
                        //do something
                    } else {
                        currentLine = "";
                    }
                } else if (c != '\r') {
                    currentLine += c;
                }
            }
        }
        client.stop();
        Serial.println("client disconnected");
    }
}

Output (when client connects):
// execution resumes here from blocking server.available() after a client connects ...

[INFO] A client connected to this server :
[PORT]: 51193
[IP]:192.168.2.36

new client connected
client disconnected

[INFO] A client connected to this server :
[PORT]: 51192
[IP]:192.168.2.36

new client connected
client disconnected

[INFO] A client connected to this server :
[PORT]: 51194
[IP]:192.168.2.36

new client connected
client disconnected

// ...continues indefinitely

According to Arduino's documentation for server.available(), the behavior observed when WiFiClient is not locally scoped isn't normal, and I've already reported the problem to the developers of the SDK I'm using. However, I'd like to understand, in general, why assigning an object within different scopes in C/C++ can cause such a change in behavior.
Aside from putting WiFiClient in a globally scoped variable, as above, I also tried making it a class member. I also tried various things to try to get it to work, such as storing a pointer or reference to the WiFiClient object, none of which worked.
I've mainly used interpreter-based languages and haven't yet encountered an issue like this. My previous experience conditioned me to believe that an object should behave relatively the same in different scopes (I'll admit that it took an embarrassing amount of time to narrow the issue down to changes in variable scope because of that expectation), so this is really new and fascinating to me.
Obviously, a more specific discussion of why what I experienced above occurred would require intimate knowledge of the Arduino framework and the SDK I'm using, so that's not what I'm asking. I'd really like to know more conceptually why such an issue can occur in the first place.

Additional detail: I forgot to mention that server.available() is blocking — although there is a non-blocking mode, it isn't enabled here to further rule out the issue being caused by that mode. The issues occur on the very first trip through loop(). Execution halts at WiFiClient client = server.available()/client = server.available() until a client connects. The Serial Monitor outputs I include start immediately after a client connects. I've also edited those outputs to make that clearer.

The loop function is called in a loop by the Arduino system code. So when client is a local variable it will be constructed and destructed every time the function is called. If it's global, then it will not be destructed between the calls.

Destructors are called on the terminating } of a scoped block.  The issue has nothing to do with Arduino -- that's how C++ works.  while (whatever) { T x; } is completely different than T x; while (whatever) { }.  The former has x alive, while the latter (as mentioned) creates and destroys x on each iteration.  If the destructor performs various things that affects the operation of x, then it is no surprise things work strangely.

There is also copy/move assignment difference with client = server.available();, whereas WiFiClient client = server.available(); call constructor.

char ssid[] = ""; and char pass[] = ""; look suspicious; they both create an array of 1 char, which clearly is not large enough to contain an SSID or a password. There's not enough code to see how these are used, but if there's a strcpy buried somewhere it's going to write out of bounds.

I suspect WiFiClient doesn't implement correctly rule of 5/3/0, so the deletion of the moved temporary impacts wrongly the instance which is still alive.

@PaulMcKenzie @Someprogrammerdude I just wanted to add some additional context: server.available() is blocking until a client connects, so it never reaches the terminating } before the error occurs (please correct me if I'm wrong). It halts at client = server.available(); until a client connects. If that's the case, shouldn't it work as normal (at least on the very first cycle through loop, before any destructors are called)?

@PeteBecker, sorry if it wasn't clear in my post, but char ssid[] = ""; and char pass[] = ""; are both redacted of my SSID and password.

@RobertErnestDelaCruz -- I'm not sure what you mean. But to clarify my point, those two arrays can each hold no more than 1 character.

@PeteBecker -- Isn't specifying the size of a character array at initialization already optional? See relevant part of doc on aggregate initialization.

@RobertErnestDelaCruz -- I'm not sure where in that documentation you're looking. char x[] = "abcd"; defines x as an array of char with 5 elements; the initializer "abcd" (which has 5 characters, including the terminating nul) determines the size of the array. char x[] = ""; defines x as an array of char with 1 element (since "" has 1 character, the terminating nul).

@PeteBecker Ah, yeah. that's why I apologized for not being clear in my post. char ssid[] = ""/char[] pass = "" is only that way because I redacted (removed) the values that were originally there (my own SSID and password). They are filled in, as they should be, in my own code. Sorry again if I wasn't clear then and earlier.

@RobertErnestDelaCruz -- okay, so they're initialized with the values that are used throughout. So there's no problem. Tip: use const char ssid[] = ""; for character data that won't be changed.

There are at least 2 differences (which are related) between the versions:

In the local version the following line:
WiFiClient client = server.available();

calls the constructor of WiFiClient.
But in the global version this line:
client = server.available();

calls the assignment operator (move/copy) which is potentially different.

The loop function is called in a loop by the Arduino system code.
Every time is it called a new instance of by this line:
WiFiClient client = server.available();

Then every time the loop function returns the scope of client will also end and it will be destructed.
This is different from the global version where the same instance of client is always used (but as mentioned above it is assigned every call of loop). Note that in the global case a temporary object is constructed for every assignment (and then destructed).


Both differences (construction vs assignment, and multiple destructions of client) are actually aspects of the same cause - the local/global scope.

"This is different from the global version where there is only one instance of client ever created." The temporary is created and deleted immediately after the assignment.

@Jarod42 you are right, corrected my answer.

Thanks for the insight. This gives me some additional info into potential issues and is the kind of signpost I was looking for to point me to the right direction. But I just wanted some clarification: The same idea holds true for local vs class scopes too, right? Because I tried that and got the same results. Also, could the construction and/or destruction of the temporary object cause potential issues even if it is incomplete at the time of first assignment (first trip through loop()) – relevant due to blocking server.available().

@RobertErnestDelaCruz (1) regarding class scope: not sure what you mean. Anyway a member of a class is alive as long as the class object is alive, and destructed when the object is. (2) the construction/destruction of the temporary object might cause problems if it does not properly implement the rule of 0/3/5.

@wohlstad Didn't know that, thanks! I've upvoted your answer.
